# Access Nested Class Statements from List

Tags: c#, list, nested-class

I have a nested class like this:

```
public class Class
{
   [System.Serializable]
   public class NestedClass
   {
             public float data;
   }

   public NestedClass data = new NestedClass() ;
};
```

I want to create a list (below is not true) from that class.

```
List<NestedClass>() list = new List<NestedClass>();
```

How can I do?

Comment: Remove the first pair of brackets, they're not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to create a list from somewhere other than inside `Class`, you'll have to create it like this:

```
List<Class.NestedClass>() list = new List<Class.NestedClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<NestedClass> list = new List<NestedClass>();
```

Just as you thought.

As @dcastro said: If you want to create a list from somewhere outside the class, you should do:

```
List<Class.NestedClass> list = new List<Class.NestedClass>();
```

But then why did you nest the class anyway?

Comment: inheriting bunch of classes from the first. But i don't want to create everytime it, so I was thinking to create nested one.